# Laptop Image disappears for a few seconds when using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, ubuntu-11.10

My laptop screen turns black every once in a while for a few seconds when I am running windows. 
I have a Dual Boot with Ubuntu 11.10/Windows 7 set up on my PC. I never got display problems with the Ubuntu OS, but when I run Windows, the image may disappear and then reappear after a couple of minutes. I get a status message that some problem occured and that my graphic card driver is now working again. 
Could you give me a clue, what could be the problem here and which things I could check on my PC to find out, what I have to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with most of the AMD and nVida devices. It indicates a crash and a detailed reports can be found in Reliability Monitor as well as in the Event Viewer (Windows System Category). Several things have to be checked. One is the temperature of the GPU (Use something like GPU Temp). If the ventilation is not sufficient it might fail. Next thing is the drivers. If there are issues with drivers its better to roll back or reinstall (latest possible). Note that the error logs may have information regarding which component crashed the device. Simple remove the background programs (unwanted) and prevent loading. Use msconfig utility and services.msc to configure the startup behavior of services and programs. Any video players with obsolete or incompatible codecs or components like Flash Player might have crashed or caused the problem. You need to check and update/remove such components.